# How can radioactive-dating techniques, such as uranium-thorium analysis, tell you when a human fashioned a tool out of a rock or coral?

Tags: radiation, radioactivity, applied-physics, radiometry

This is an archaeology or anthropology question....

Scientists in a recent 'Nature' said they compared recent genetic analyses of theirs, concerning when Polynesian islands were first settled, with colleagues' dating of coral artifacts using uranium-thorium analysis....

How can radioactive dating tell you when a human broke off a chunk of coral and fashioned an instrument out of it?

'Luminescence' dating has been all the rage recently, because it can tell you when an artefact was last exposed to sunlight, but....

Comment: wikipedia has a good article about this.

Comment: Coral, yes, also wood, because they were once living organisms. Not so for rock.

Answer (score 1):

When ind doubt , start with [wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiometric_dating)

> Radiometric dating, radioactive dating or radioisotope dating is a technique which is used to date materials such as rocks or carbon, in which trace radioactive impurities were selectively incorporated when they were formed. The method compares the abundance of a naturally occurring radioactive isotope within the material to the abundance of its decay products, which form at a known constant rate of decay.

In the particular case of the coral, when it was cut and brought to land it stopped replenishing various atoms, and the radioactive ones would stay within the cut coral, and decay. In natural environments the coral will take up and discharge  matter as waste products, as all living systems.